# Can you go from a gas to a liquid without condensating through supercritical fluids?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, states-of-matter, phase-diagram, condensation

If you were to take a gas like co2 and then heat it up and pressurize it in a specific way, would it theoretically be possible to turn the gas to liquid without using condensation? This would be hard to do I imagine, but is theoretically possible?

Comment: Usually going from gas to liquid is called condensation. So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: My memories are too vague to make a real answer, but yes you can. Years ago, I had a colleague (teacher) who loved to use a small box containing a specific fluid that was usually liquid, but very close to fluid transition. By playing with pressure with a vacuum pump and temperature with a hair dryer, he was able to do exactly what you describe: liquid -> fluid (vanishing meniscus) -> gas.

Comment: If the gas is above its critical temperature, no amount of pressurization will produce two phases (e.g., liquid and vapor) together.

Answer (score 1):

Not hard. A trajectory with constant temperature or pressure segments goes as follows: heat gas above the critical temperature. Pressurize it above the critical pressure. Cool it to the intended liquid temperature. Depressurize to intended liquid pressure (not too low, or it'll evaporate).